# QUnit test AJAX callback result

Tags: javascript, ajax, qunit

I am new here. I have read through the old posts about QUnit and AJAX but still couldn't get a clue. I have a function that does an AJAX call and manipulate the webpage based on the result:

```
myObj.prototype.getName = function() {
  $.get('/url/to/server/', {id: this.id})
    .done(function(data) {
      var name = JSON.parse(data);
      var html = '<p>' + id.toString() + ': ' + name + '</p>';
      $('.content').append(html);
    });
};
```

I want to test whether this entire function is successful. Following QUnit 2.x's [cookbook](https://qunitjs.com/cookbook/), I did:

```
QUnit.test('myObj.getName', function(assert) {
  var done = assert.async();
  var obj = new myObj(1);  // 1 is the ID
  obj.getName();
  setTimeout(function() {
    assert.equal($('.content').html(), '<p>1: name-of-1</p>');
    done();
  });
});
```

The function itself works and prints the name to the webpage, but in the QUnit test, $('.content').html() is None. It seems that the test fires up before the callback function completes.

Any ideas on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `setTimeout` is not actually waiting for the Ajax call to complete, it simply waits for the Ajax call to begin, thus freeing up the JS engine to run the next function... your setTimeout. At some later point in time the Ajax call completes and your `done` callback is executed. The best solution is to *not use `setTimeout` at all*... instead, try returning your Ajax call from the source code function. This should allow you to hook into the Promise in your test:

```
myObj.prototype.getName = function() {
  // notice the new `return` on the line below!
  return $.get('/url/to/server/', {id: this.id})
    .done(function(data) {
      var name = JSON.parse(data);
      var html = '<p>' + id.toString() + ': ' + name + '</p>';
      $('.content').append(html);
    });
};
```

Then in your test code you can use the returned promise:

```
QUnit.test('myObj.getName', function(assert) {
  var done = assert.async();
  var obj = new myObj(1);  // 1 is the ID
  obj.getName()
    .done(function() {
      assert.equal($('.content').html(), '<p>1: name-of-1</p>');
      done();
    });
});
```